# Angular material UI dragHandle inverse

Tags: angular, angular-material, drag-and-drop

I want to drag the element using the entire div for cdkDrag other than the button within it. Its basically the inverse of cdkDragHandle in the material UI.

[image]

The entire drag box should be draggable except the button "Cannot drag here". The button should not move itself  or the container within which it resides.

```
<div class="example-box m-3" cdkDrag>

    <div class="example-handle">
        <button>Cannot drag here</button>
    </div>
    Drag here works
</div>
```